# What is the most effective way to make normalized data available to reporting software

Tags: t-sql, reporting, user-defined-functions, entity-attribute-value, denormalization

We have some data in a normalized structure that is a form of the [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) pattern.  We need to make this data available for reporting, but it has to be transformed prior to use.

[image]
(This image represents the data structure; actual schema has different names and more columns, pertinent columns are displayed)

Different *ObjectTypes* have different columns.  We want to create a report for an individual object type, but we cannot simply join object to value and filter on object type.  That results in a single column, where what we actually want is to perform some kind of "pivot" where the values are mapped into columns by their *ColumnIDs*.

Processing this within application logic is simple, but I need to expose the un-EAV'd data as a View with the correct columns for each object type, so that any reporting software that can access these tables can consume them.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Reporting tools don't care what the schema looks like. All the tools you mentioned will technically report off this. I think you are asking "how do I transform this to make more sense to an end user". As mentioned in other answers, you can use views, stored procedures etc. but first you need to know what you want it to look like. This kind of schema is tricky because if for example you create a dozen custom views to represent a dozen objects, then when a new object is created you need to create a new view.

Comment: Thank you @Nick.McDermaid you have expressed my question better than I.  I'm trying to find a way to make the data make more sense to our end users.  If we use views we would need to create a new one every time users add a new ObjectType and edit the view every time they change ObjectTypeColumns.

Comment: If possible, I'd like to avoid making a data warehoused copy of the data for reporting, but I don't know what options I have outside of views.

Comment: This unfortunately is a characteristic of EAV models - basically the designer has 'put off' creating a 'proper' data model. The data modelling is now pushed back to the next layer (reporting). Really it comes down to understanding the business - are there key entities that you can model or is the business _really_ that agile and flexible that they need to complex new objects on the fly?

Comment: As it turns out we are in a business horizontal which necessitates some vertical data structures.  Our clients can have hundreds of ObjectTypes of which only a few are common across them and many of them get created without our knowledge.  This data structure has been about perfect for every aspect of the application, less reports. The search engine is fast, easy to use and was relatively easy to create.

Comment: We're now experimenting with creating a view per ObjectType as well as using ETL to create and maintain a separate repository to report against.  Don't really like either option so far, therefore I posted here to see if there are other options known by the community.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram you posted looks like a diagram in Access or SQLServer. You can create view/query in both or a stored procedure in SQL Server and use it directly in any reporting software . You can also define a SQL command inside the report. BTW, tables ObjectTypeColumns and ObjectValues have composite primary key , which is not a good practice.

Comment: Thank you Lan.  Yes the diagram was done in sql server.  Can you recommend a query that meets the requirements stated?

Comment: What kind of reporting software you are going to use ?

Comment: As far as ObjectTypeColumns and ObjectValue.  They are both Many-to-Many tables and it is a well established best practice to use composite keys on m2m as it gives you use of clustered index for queries in the primary direction (ObjectID then ValueID). And only requires a second index to fully cover the m2m (in this case on ValueID).

Comment: The reporting layer needs to be accessible to a wide variety of reporting tools, including but not limited to Crystal, SSRS, many open source reporting tools.  That is ultimately my dilemma. I could easily flatten the data in a logic layer and make a single report but that doesn't meet my requirements.  Many tools need to be able to report against it.

Comment: you say that I can create a view or sproc, GREAT. Can you recommend a query that would flatten the data as described in the question?  It needs to be filtered on ObjectTypeID.